# how to configure mod_proxy_ftp

Tags: apache, apache2, mod-proxy

Im struggling to find any example of how i can configure the module mod_proxy_ftp

```
# Reverse Proxy
#
ProxyRequests On
#ProxyPreserveHost On
<Proxy *>
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from 192.168.10.0
</Proxy>
ProxyPass /ftp_folder ftp://someserver:9021
</IfModule>
</IfModule>
```

The reason im using a apache as a choice, is because we dont have permission to install any other software into our server, and they gave the idea of using this module.

Anyone could give me a light on this?

thanks for reading.